# How to check for wired internet connection in UWP?

Tags: c#, .net, networking, uwp

How to find whether the user is connecting to the internet using wired?

Here are my current progress

```
var internetConnectionProfile = Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();

if (internetConnectionProfile.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() == Windows.Networking.Connectivity.NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess)
{
    // has internet connection
}
if (internetConnectionProfile.IsWwanConnectionProfile)
{
    // its mobile
}
if (internetConnectionProfile.IsWlanConnectionProfile)
{
    // its wireless
}
```

Comment: Just bear in mind. *As soon* as your code has obtained an answer, and before it takes any action based on it, the actual reality may be different (e.g. user just plugged/unplugged a cable as your code was running. Or moved out of wireless range and fell back to mobile, as just two possible examples)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
bool IsWiredInternetAccess()
    {
IReadOnlyList<ConnectionProfile> connections = NetworkInformation.GetConnectionProfiles();

        foreach (var connection in connections)
     {
            if (connection == null) continue;

            if (connection.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() == NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess)
        {
       // check is connection wired
       if ((connection.ConnectionProfile.IsWlanConnectionProfile)||(connection.IsWwanConnectionProfile))
          {
           // connection is Wlan or Wwan
           return false;
          }
       else
          {
           return true;
          }
        }       
     }
    }
```

Comment: So what the code does is, it check for internet connection. And if internet connection available and is not from wireless or mobile, then internet connection must be from wired. Am I correct? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you right. I have change answer and put code into a method that returns boolean value.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple and updated answer

Updated [ConnectionProfile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.networking.connectivity.connectionprofile?view=winrt-19041) class helps to identify ,type of network connection.

```
ConnectionProfile connectionProfile = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();
bool isWifi = connectionProfile.IsWlanConnectionProfile;
```